# RPC: Interfacing C# and legacy C++ XDR

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, rpc, xdr

I have multiple legacy devices with defined RPC interfaces, written in C++ XDR (.x) files.
I need to access these devices from a modern C# application, in other words to implement new RPC C# client matching old C++ RPC servers.

One of the free options I found is the Google Protocol Buffers, however I have some doubts.

1. General suggestions on choice? Will that work - "C++ XDR" <--> "Protobuf C#"?
2. Can the XDR(.x) files be converted to Proto2 or Proto3(.proto) style of Protocol Buffers?

Thanks,
Igor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I started looking in other directions.

The easiest, operational and free C# RPC solution I found was "RemoteTea.NET" SourceForge project - port of the pure Java RemoteTea package.
It has RPCgen implementation (not perfect, but operational), PortMapper class and base classes for RPC XDR handling.
It took me few days to implement the clients for 3 RPC servers.

Thanks,

Igor.